# Cracked rafter fix and loose truss plates

Tags: drywall, ceiling, roof, truss

I appear to have a crack on my drywall where it meets the ceiling in my bedroom.

The crack is spreading a bit. I went in the attic and noticed that this rafter beam is cracked and might be causing the ceiling in my room to lift? I'm not 100% sure what's going on here.

But on my other side of the home I'm developing a crack running down my ceiling. On this side of my home I noticed a few truss mending plates have come undone against the rafter.

I'm in Sacramento so we suffered a 5 year severe drought only to be completely drenched this past winter. Now that we're in the middle of Summer were experiencing a ton of heat and our clay soil is cracking all over our yard.

Wondering what's the best approach to repairs at this stage. Do I have foundation issues? Or is it just some wood expansion and shrinkage that's pulling my drywall apart. Do I patch the drywall or call a foundation expert?

This time of year last year I do have some door frames that go out of square leading to minor adjustments and it's been this way for the last two years I have lived here.

[image]

[image]

More pictures
[image]
[image]
[image]
Edit:
These are extra pictures, as you can see in the picture 1, ignore the temporary patch job, but the wall and the ceiling have a split and it crossed that piece of drywall, behind the wire for the lamp I put up is a gap about 1/2" wide. You could literally push up on that ceiling piece with your hand and it'll go up.

Picture 2. On the opposite side of the house, in the living room is that straight line crack that is crawling down from the ceiling.

The final picture is just a different part of the house where there are signs of bad drywall patch jobs that were done before we moved in that are starting to show more, like drywall tape that seems to be cracking.

Answer (score 2):

The split top cord should be repaired. Lay a 6 or 8 ft long 2x4 or 2x6 across 3 or 4 of the bottom cords, then use a length of 2x4 to push up to close the  split. When it is aligned properly, nail it in place with numerous nails that are the type that do not causing splitting.  Then sister on 3 or 4 ft (or more) of 2x4 on one side of the repaired section. If protruding roofing nails prevent sistering on either side, then you might have to use a 2x3 on the side and on the bottom edge.

(You might squirt wood glue into the crack before pressing the crack closed.)

Comment: So using a 2x4 or 2x6 I'm creating a floor to use as a jack to lift my cracked rafter up til it reconnects before mending it with nails and sistering it. Is it something that can be done on my own as far as the weight loaded on top of the roof? I know there's nothing above it but a shingle roof so just thinking about the amount of force I'll need to exert. And also thank you for the tips.

Comment: In most trusses the top cord is in compression. It is possible that pushing up  will force it out of alignment. If that happens, you might have to attach a guide to one side of the top cord.

Comment: I doubt that you would be able to force it back in place with one hand while nailing or screwing with another. At the suggestion of an experienced builder who had started as a framer I used this technique to push up a section of roof decking before putting in blocking to hold it up. It takes a lot of force to shift framing members. When your (out of plumb) vertical brace is snug by hand you will be required to tap (or pound) on the horizontal 2x6 to shift it to raise the split top cord into place. It will take at least 100 lbf to close the split and hold it in place while you nail or screw it.

Comment: Are there any videos on YouTube which could show me some techniques to push up properly. Funny thing I think you answered my previous question about fixing a retaining wall as well, Jim S.

Comment: I don't know of any Youtube videos on this. In my own case I positioned the 2x6 across the bottom cords (celing joists) and happened to have a length of 2x4 that I positioned at an angle along the 2x6 such that when I pounded it with a hammer (on the bottom) the bottom slid along the 2x6 becoming more upright and so raising the roof decking which had sagged. IIRC the 2x6 did not move or at least very much.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a hydraulic bottle jack to raise the 2x4.

Comment: So the 2x4 you hammered against was most likely a considerable length long in order to have it push up against the top cord while resting on the bottom cord and not moving by too much. I do own a hydraulic car jack as well, sounds like a good plan. Are there any specific nail types I can use, as I read that using screws for putting the sister 2x4 in would easily shear off and 16 penny nails would split the wood.

Comment: The 2x4 I used was about 5' or 6' long. Our house has a low pitch roof 3-in-12 so the attic space is not very high. Get up in your attic with a tape measure and determine what length of 2x4 you would need. The bottle jack is not that good an idea (1) they are heavy and if you would drop it in the attic you would damage the ceiling (2) you risk the jack flipping as you jack if the jack is not lifting perfectly straight

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jim Stewart , it needs to be fixed.

However, I think I'm missing something. The trusses on the left side of the peak are different than those on the right side. Is there a reason for this? Maybe this is causing the cracked ceiling and the door problems.

If the ceiling is cracked EXACTLY where it meets the wall, then it could be from 1) lack of attic ventilation, or 2) lumber that was installed "green" and shrunk over time when it dried out.

1) I don't see any soffit vents. They're needed and you need to verify why you don't have them...maybe other vents somewhere?

2) Look for a grade stamp on the HORIZONTAL lumber near where the ceiling is cracked. If it's marked, "Grn", this means Green lumber was used. (If the ink in the grade stamp is smeared, this means it was wet when they applied the grade stamp and it is definitely "Green".

I doubt the foundation is the problem, unless you have wall cracks too, (I.e.: cracks in wallboard at the corners of doors and windows).

Comment: As far as I can tell I don't have any soffits outside, let alone soffit vents.

There are these chimney like vents up on the roof itself, there are two of those.

I can't get to the horizontal lumber near the part of the cracked ceiling because it's pretty tight down there, I got a pretty high pitch, never really measured it but it's at least 6/12 I'd say.

I think the reason it's different on both sides of the trusses because one side has a higher vaulted ceiling than the other side. I'm getting the crack in the same center area on both sides of the house.

The house was built in 83

Comment: @HarrisonT If you don't have cracks at the corners of your doors and windows, then it's not the foundation.  Hmmm...no vents??  Soffit vents allow "cross ventilation". This removes moisture from the attic and helps prevent dryrot. Plus, it helps cool the attic.    Where you live, you don't have snow, so you won't have a failure until you walk on the roof.

Comment: Do I need to concern myself that some of those staple like plates are coming undone? I'm going to perform the sister method Jim suggested as soon as I can get some help from my uncle who does his own work at home. So I'm confident he'll be more familiar with the whole sistering process.

Comment: Yes. Those gussets are critical and handle much force. You'll need a very robust repair, such as 3/4" plywood gussets, twice as large as the steel ones, bolted and glued to each side.

Comment: Could the gussets be glued and nailed or screwed? That would be a lot easier than bolting. Another way to pull the split top cord into place might be screws from below. I would try 3" or 3.25" long screws of the type which are optimized for clamping. These have a long unthreaded section next to the head so that it will pull a gap closed. If the screw is fully threaded all the way to the head it will not clamp as well or at all, e.g., http://www.decksdirect.com/grk-fasteners-5-1-16-rss-rugged-structural-screw.html

Comment: you *might* try this: start in the area where there is about equal thickness of material on both sides of the crack and *start* 3 or 4 screws and go from one to another progressively tightening them pulling the crack closed. If you have screws with threads all the way to the head, you might have to drill through the underside part of the cracked member so the threads don't engage. The threads should only engage the upper side.

Comment: Yes, those plates transfer the loads from the roof (top chord) to the web chords. If several steel plates are coming loose, that's a sign that green lumber was used in the trusses. As it dries out, hey shrink and "squeeze" the teeth of the plate out of the lumber. To fix the gusset plates, I'd use one of the methods suggested by @isherwood or Jim Steward. I like the idea of using screws, rather than nails. This will be better than banging the truss with a hammer. Be careful not to split the wood.

Comment: The diagonal crack (that has been patched) in Picture 1 above the doorway is exactly what you don't want. It can be caused by a couple of things: 1) foundation settling, or 2) green lumber drying out, or 3) bad install. The diagonal patch didn't "open up" again, so it's probably not the foundation. Because the cracks are occurring in several locations, it's probably a combo of 2) and 3). The long (4' long) straight cracks could be because the wallboard was not lapped onto a support sufficiently so the nailing didn't "take". Because of where you live, it's not due to extreme temperatures.

Comment: Does green wood take this long to dry up? My place isn't new by any standard having been built in 83 the year I was born I'd say it's almost 35 years in age. I'm going to perform the gusset repair when the temps drop hopefully by September as this July has been over 95 degrees on many days straight. Now the cracked top cord my uncle suggests replacing that piece, but I'm unsure it's doable by just the two of us, especially with both of us having only handyman level skills, would it be possible? And thank you everyone for providing value tips thus far.

Comment: Who knows what "triggers" the split...I would guess it's been that way for some time. I would not "replace" the split piece, merely "repair" it. It's nailed from above and would be difficult to remove. Remember, the repair doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: I see wood used in my garage truss says Grn on it not smeared though. Some of those gusset plates were slowly separating as well but not to the degree of my attic, the garage doesn't have a ceiling so maybe the ventilation is much better there? Not sure. Anyway, I found that there are these tiny soffit vents resting on the east and west part of the house. There were only one on each side, feels inadequate.

Comment: Code required attic vents should be 1/150 the area of the attic, except the area can be reduced to 1/300 if half the area is in the top one-half of the attic. You are way under. I still doubt it's a foundation problem. I'd fix the split(s) in the trusses chords and then the cracks in the gypsum board...and then monitor it for a year or so. You probably won't have any more problems. If you don't have moisture (condensation) in the attic, you may not need to add more vents.

Comment: I don't see any moisture issues, our home inspector said there had been a roof leak repaired before we bought this house. Thanks for the help, going to get to the fixes after this summer is over as it sounds like it's structurally sound.